# Trying to float image to right of text

Tags: html, css, image

When I float the food.png to the right and try and get the text to float around it, it doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions?

HTML

```
<div id="main">
        <article>
            <h2>Why Sunflower Seeds?</h2>
                <img src="images/seed.png" alt="seed" class="seed">
                <p class="why">Sunflower seeds are an excellent source of vitamin E, the body's primary fat-soluble antioxidant. Vitamin E travels throughout the body neutralizing free radicals that would otherwise damage fat-containing structures and molecules, such as cell membranes, brain cells, and cholesterol. By protecting these cellular and molecular components, vitamin E has significant anti-inflammatory effects that result in the reduction of symptoms in asthma, osteoarthritis, and rheumatoid arthritis, conditions where free radicals and inflammation play a big role. Vitamin E has also been shown to reduce the risk of colon cancer, help decrease the severity and frequency of hot flashes in women going through menopause, and help reduce the development of diabetic complications.</p><img src="images/food.png" alt="food" class="food">
        </article>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.food {
width: 43%;
float: right;
margin-top: -150px;}

p.why {
margin-right: 15px;
margin-left: 25px;
font-family: century gothic;
line-height: 1.7em;
font-weight: bold;
clear: both;
font-size: 12px;
position: relative;}
```

Comment: If I may give you some other advice: your `font-family` is invalid. Should be `"Century Gothic", sans-serif;`

Comment: Why do you put a negative top margin on your image?

Comment: just trying to play around with it.. i've taken it out at this point.

Comment: OK. So then why are you clearing the paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the food image inside the `<p>`, at the top, float it to the right and remove the `margin-top`. Then remove the float right from `<p>`. Done

```css
.why {
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  font-family: "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
}

.food {
  width: 43%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h2>Why Sunflower Seeds?</h2>
  <img src="images/seed.png" alt="seed" class="seed">
  <p class="why">
    <img src="images/food.png" alt="food" class="food">
    Sunflower seeds are an excellent source of vitamin E, the body's primary fat-soluble antioxidant. Vitamin E travels throughout the body neutralizing free radicals that would otherwise damage fat-containing structures and molecules, such as cell membranes, brain cells, and cholesterol. By protecting these cellular and molecular components, vitamin E has significant anti-inflammatory effects that result in the reduction of symptoms in asthma, osteoarthritis, and rheumatoid arthritis, conditions where free radicals and inflammation play a big role. Vitamin E has also been shown to reduce the risk of colon cancer, help decrease the severity and frequency of hot flashes in women going through menopause, and help reduce the development of diabetic complications.
  </p>
</article>
```

Comment: this is the answer. Beat me by 5sec!

Comment: This is 99% perfect! Fixes my issue for sure! Would I just adjust margins to get the image at the bottom of the paragraph instead of the top? Thanks again for the assist, Patrik!

Comment: Not possible with CSS alone.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2944164/1166161, you'd have to use JavaScript as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean make the text float left? and the food.png float right?

If that so, just add `float:left;` at your `p.why` class

Comment: I tried that already, doesn't seem to be doing anything. This is the link for the project.

http://gc200298785.computerstudi.es/assignmenttwo/index2.html

Answer (score 0):

`p` is a block element by default.

And all block elements are displayed in separate blocks.

So make your p.why inline element. By just adding `display:inline;` style to your `p.why` element

Answer (score 0):

Put your image inside and at the beginning of your `<p>` and then the wrap will work. (I used a different image just so I could see it).

```
<div id="main">
    <article>
        <h2>Why Sunflower Seeds?</h2>
        <img src="images/seed.png" alt="seed" class="seed"/>
        <p class="why"><img src="https://kalabalu.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/716-649x649.jpg" alt="food" class="food"/>Sunflower seeds are an excellent source of vitamin E, the body's primary fat-soluble antioxidant. Vitamin E travels throughout the body neutralizing free radicals that would otherwise damage fat-containing structures and molecules, such as cell membranes, brain cells, and cholesterol. By protecting these cellular and molecular components, vitamin E has significant anti-inflammatory effects that result in the reduction of symptoms in asthma, osteoarthritis, and rheumatoid arthritis, conditions where free radicals and inflammation play a big role. Vitamin E has also been shown to reduce the risk of colon cancer, help decrease the severity and frequency of hot flashes in women going through menopause, and help reduce the development of diabetic complications.</p>
    </article>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.food {
float:right;
}
```